# Javascript select cells in a table Lasso-style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to Javascript and I'm having trouble creating a Lasso - style table selection tool.

Basically, I want to be able to drag the mouse over a table and have all the cells in that area get highlighted, so I can do something later with the selected cells.

Here is a very buggy fiddle of what I am trying to achieve.   http://jsfiddle.net/kooldave98/ad5Z9/

```
var element = $("#rectangle");
// on mousedown
$(window).mousedown(function (e1) {
    // first move element on mouse location
    element.show().css({ top: e1.pageY, left: e1.pageX });
    // resize that div so it will be resizing while moouse is still pressed
    var resize = function (e2) {
        // you should check for direction in here and moves with top or left
        element.width(e2.pageX - e1.pageX);
        element.height(e2.pageY - e1.pageY);
    };
    $(window).mousemove(resize);
    // and finally unbind those functions when mouse click is released
    var unbind = function () {
        $(window).unbind(resize);
        $(window).unbind(unbind);
    };
    $(window).mouseup(unbind);
});
```

I need to be able to move the selection tool in any direction within the table and select additional cells afterwards using the "ctrl" key.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the jQuery UI [Selectable](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/) widget.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, once you've included the jQuery UI Selectable widget, you can just do

```
$('table').selectable(
    filter: 'td',      // Ensure elements are selected by table cell
);
```

Then in your CSS, you have the classes `.ui-selecting` and `.ui-selected` that you can set to your desired highlight color. E.g.

```
.ui-selecting {
    background: red;
}
.ui-selected {
    background: blue;
}
```

You will also have some default selection behaviors you may not want. Here's how I get rid of them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').mousedown(function(event) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Though hopefully you have something more specific to select on than just `table`. :)